# BCM2836/BCM2837 in Aarch64 mode - how to generate an exception in a bare metal program?

Tags: exception, cpu, arm64

I'm sort of experimenting with AArch64, and I've set up my "OS" to run in EL1. The IRQ vector table is loaded and working, etc. And if I make a mistake in alignment I get a nice exception where I print out ESR and ELR. But... Can I generate my own exception? I want the same behavior (i.e. print out ESR, ELR and restart) if some condition in EL1 is true, something like if (cond == 1) generate_exception()... Is that possible, or is generating exceptions only up to the CPU?

Specifically, if it's CPU-specific, it's on the Raspberry Pi 3B+, so BCM2837B0 ARM Cortex A-53...

Comment: What is the exact Aarch64 CPU you are targeting  (brand/model) ?

Comment: I added it in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your question has more to do with the proprietary interrupt controller used in the BCM2836/BCM2837 than with Aarch64 per se.

I would suggest to use a mailbox interrupt, as documented in this [document](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2836/QA7_rev3.4.pdf).

Another valuable source of information would be the [Raspberry Pi Bare Bones project](https://wiki.osdev.org/Raspberry_Pi_Bare_Bones), since it does provide code using interrupts and mailboxes.

With an Aarch64 processor using a standard GIC, you could have sent a SGI (Software Generated Interrupt) to any of the four cores.

Comment: @samuzu.pazael: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is of course no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could use an SVC.

Supervisor Call (previously called SWI, Software Interrupt).